# How to concat int resource id R.string.id_name + _1 like we do with string?

Tags: android

Example:

```
if (i = 1) getString("R.string.name_user" + "_1");
```

I want to add a suffix to string resource id.
How can I do the above but the value that will pass to `getString()` will be `int`, not a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Resources.getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

1. `int id = resources.getIdentifier("name_user{your-suffix}", "string", "your-package-name")`
2. then `getString(id)`

**Note: You should avoid doing this, it is not efficient.**

Comment: Thanks, I have to accept your answer because you provide explanation. Could you tell me why it is not efficient beside it being ugly coding?

Comment: Sure. I did a fast search in the Android source code but did not find the exact implementation, but there are two possibilities. The first one is that reflection is used to find the corresponding field of R.java by name (reflection is slow). The second is that provided resource name is compared against all resources until it finds a match (or not) and this is also slow. Keep in mind that comparing strings is slower than comparing integers. In contrast the resource identifier gets you quicker to your resource. And finally, the documentation discourages using getIdentifier() so I would trust it.

Answer (score 4):

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_user" + "_1", "string", getPackageName());
String result = getString(id);
```